# KeyCloak with Domainname

Tags: keycloak

I have an server, running IIS and some c#-WebApis. I can call this services with http://domainname:port . Thats ok.
On this server I have a Keycloak installed (IIS not involved) and I can access Keycloak via http://localhost:8080.
But not over http://domainname:8080 .
Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially your Keycloak binds to 127.0.0.1 and not your public IP. Try to start Keycloak with the correct binding address, like so:

```sh
./standalone.bat -Djboss.bind.address=<IP address or host name>
```

or so

```sh
./standalone.bat -b <IP address or host name>
```

You could also specify `0.0.0.0` as `<IP address or host name>` to bind to all IPs.